# git privacy in node apps deployment to Heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, sails.js

I am new to Heroku but I managed to deploy my development first Sails@beta to Heroku, I created a Heroku app and submitted my git commits to the git repository provided by Heroku.

**Is the git repository provided by Heroku Private?**

Is there any possibility to track changes from a UI (something like GitHub)? or do I need to buy a private Git repository and link it to Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku is not a source code management service like GitHub; it's a Platform-as-a-Service (Paas) hosting company that happens to use Git for deployment. They do not provide any graphical interface for browsing your repository, and in fact it is probably not a good idea to use Heroku as your primary code repository.

As explained [in their documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) and treat that as canonical.

Access to clone a repository from Heroku is private, controlled by the same SSH keys you use for deployment.

There are many services that offer free private Git hosting. [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) and the cloud-hosted version of [GitLab](http://gitlab.com/) are two examples.